Reusing grid coordinates in perl Tk
I have an application that is reading data off a file system and dynamically creating widgets in a 3x3 grid based on the contents of the files. If I need to replace one of the widgets (or lack of) with a new widget worth of information, what happens to the original widget that was there (example below). Trying to avoid any potential memory leaks if this app is running for a long time.
foreach my $i (0..2) {
    foreach my $j (0..2) {
        my $box = $mw->Label(-text => "$i/$j")->grid(-row=> $i, -column => $j);
    }
}

my $replacementBox = $mw->Label(-text => "replacement")->grid(-row=> 1, -column => 1);

It successfully replaces the widget in the example, but couldn't find results when googling this question. Thanks!

I tried to replace the box many times, explicitly keeping all the previous boxes in an array, but the memory consumption increase was really tiny. If you don't plan to create hundred of thousands of the boxes, you don't need to worry about memory.
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Tk qw{ MainLoop };

my $mw = 'MainWindow'->new;

for my $i (0..2) {
    for my $j (0..2) {
        my $box = $mw->Label(-text => "$i/$j")->grid(-row=> $i, -column => $j);
    }
}

my @boxes;
$mw->repeat(10, sub {
         push @boxes, $mw->Label(
             -text => "replacement " . $#boxes)
         ->grid(-row=> 1, -column => 1);
});

MainLoop();

What's more important is when you need to redraw the window with thousands of boxes, it takes a long time to find the one that should actually be shown. To prevent that, call
    $box->destroy;

on the old $box before creating a new one.
